# What's the difference between RED and VPN?

Tags: vpn, security, virtual, remote, sophos

I know that **RED** is *Remote Ethernet Device* and **VPN** is *Virtual Private Network*.

But I think that they work as the same way.

Someone can help me?

Comment: RED normally means Random Early Detection, which is a QoS technique to prevent queues from filling to tail-drop and causing TCP global synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Remote Ethernet Device" is a Sophos marketing term for their (slave/remote-site) VPN appliances.

https://docs.sophos.com/nsg/sophos-firewall/17.5/Help/en-us/webhelp/onlinehelp/glossentries/RemoteEthernetDevice.html